# How to select specific friends in facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

This code chooses one random friend:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me() ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

How can I choose a random friend, but only with female gender?

Answer (score 0):

Gender is represented as "sex" column in users table. So, you may use:

> sex="female"

For more reference check this : [User](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/)